# Update is not working nor throwing an error

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net

I trying to update a record from ASP.Net page but there is no problem with the script and I am not receiving any error. Any suggestion are appreciated.

```
protected void update()
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str))
        {
            string command = @"update dbo.Programs set ProgCode=@ProgCode,ProgTitle=@ProgTitle,ProgDescription=@ProgDescription,ProgBudget=@ProgBudget,ProgStartDate=@ProgStartDate,ProgEndDate=@ProgEndDate where ProgId=@ProgId";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProgId", Request.QueryString["UpdProg"]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProgCode", Code.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProgTitle", Titlebox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProgDescription", Description.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProgBudget", Budget.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProgStartDate", StartDate.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProgEndDate", EndDate.Text);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Status.Text = ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

When the Update button is clicked this method is executed:

```
protected void UpdateRecord(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    update();
}
```

Thank you for your comments the problems is solved i was calling another method (UpdateSelector) on Page_Load that was making the problem

Comment: You have to debug the program using break points. Put an break point in update method and see where the program halts. May be problem is some where else in your code

Comment: Also see if the progid is in database becouse if progid cell is not in database cmnd execute successfuly but don't update any record

Comment: What is the data type of the column ProgId? Request.QueryString[...] returns a string whereas the id usually is an integer or GUID. If the WHERE clause does not match any records, no rows will be updated and no error is raised. So you should check the value of Request.QueryString["UpdProg"] in the debugger.

Comment: Check result if `ExecuteNonQuery` returned number of this method shows if any record affected in database or not. if there is no record affected then you should check your where parameter.

Comment: Mr. Markus I change the value of where class to static 1 but still having same issue. Do you any other suggestion

Comment: Use SQL Server Profiler to see the actual UPDATE command being sent.
From there you should be able to see if your Update() method is generating an invalid UPDATE command, and the clue to fix it.